# 23.10.1 UEFI boot fails: Could not create MOKlistXRT: Out of resources

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I had the Ubuntu 23.10 version running on an **ASUS machine**(X556UAK) along windows, and all of a sudden, the machine crashed and rendered the below error message while booting:

```
could not reate MOKL
istRT: volmefull
could not create MOKLISTXRT: volume full
could not create SbatLevelRT: volume full
could not create MoklistTrustedRT: volume full
Sonethng has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_State() faled: volume Full
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue

Comment: "volume full" ... extend the partition this is about, it seems to be full.

Comment: How to do it. It fails in booting

Comment: https://gparted.org/livecd.php  for instance. if you don't have one you need another computer to make it. You can also do this from the normal Ubuntu installer but you need to install gparted and it will be very slow.

Comment: I have ubuntu installer on usb but the issue is not able to boot .I am getting the error as soon as power on the machine.i don't want the old ubuntu anymore .please let me know how to install fresh one.i mean how to clean up the bios or grub or something.anyway i have cleaned ubuntu grub files from windows10.i guess some leftover is still there

Comment: @Rinzwind any update

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks, I resolved